# RxJava/Helidon [make asynchronous functions run inorder]

Tags: reactive-programming, completable-future, helidon

I am trying to run the below three functions one after the other:

- void f1(String id, Handler1 handler)
- void f2(String id,Handler2 handler)
- void f3(String id, Handler3 handler)

The completion of the individual functions is passed in the corresponding handler and is set in the individual function.

```
Single<String> single = Single.just("some-random-id");
single.flatMapSingle(id -> {
                            Single<String> s1 = Single.just(id);
                            f1(id,result -> {
                                if(!result.success)
                                    s1 = Single.error(result.error);
                            });
                            return s1;
                        }
                )
                .flatMapSingle(id -> {
                            Single<String> s2 = Single.just(id);
                            f2(id,result -> {
                                if(!result.success)
                                    s2 = Single.error(result.error);
                            });
                            return s2;
                        }
                        )
                .flatMapSingle(id -> {
                            Single<String> s3 = Single.just(id);
                            f3(id,result -> {
                                if(!result.success)
                                    s3 = Single.error(result.error);
                            });
                            return s3;
                        }).onError(error->{
                                 System.out.println(error.message);
                        });
single.get();
```

The problem that  is that the code doesnt wait for result.success and the onError is never triggered
How can i make sure that singles in flatMaps are initialized correctly based on result.success ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, those assignments from the handler can't ever work; the variable is out of scope and the parent method might have finished returning long ago.

What you could do is use a `CompletableFuture` to mediate the callback back to a `Single`:

```java
single.flatMapSingle(id -> {
    CompletableFuture<String> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
    f1(id, result -> {
        if (result.success) {
            future.complete(id);
        } else {
            future.completeExceptionally(result.error);
        }
    });
    return Single.create(future);
})
// same pattern for f2 & f3
```